# inputenc error with romanian diacritics

Tags: input-encodings

I am using this packages to write with Romanian diacritics:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[romanian]{babel}
```

The problem is that it worked before with this setting, now it doesn't work. What is the problem? Can someone help me? Sometimes works, sometimes doesn't.

Comment: I think you shouldn't load `ucs` at all. But it's only a guess, please, provide a [full minimal example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) on which we can find the problem.

Comment: Actually I am using Atom to build latex files, and I have switched to use another package. Work well now. Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has solved it himself.

Comment: It is probably relevant that the Romanian diacritics were added to inputenc's utf8 option in the October 2105 LaTeX Release.

Answer (score 2):

As documented in ltnews 23, Support for romanian comma under accented letters  ȘșȚț was added to `inputenc` in the 2015/10/01 release, so with current releases, no additional definitions are needed and the following works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[romanian]{babel}

\begin{document}

these: ȘșȚț

\end{document}
```